# How to make all keys, from a schema, not required

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup

I'm looking for a simple way to transform a yup schema to the same schema without any required field.

```
const requiredSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  description: yup.string().required(),
})
// to
const notRequiredSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string(),
  description: yup.string(),
})
```

I am looking for a function to apply on either `requiredSchema` or `notRequiredSchema`. The idea looks kind of like the Partial key word for types (TS) but for yup objects basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup supports this in the [1.0.0 beta versions](https://github.com/jquense/yup/releases). If you're not ok with using the beta version you could snag the [code](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/object.ts#L383) they're using to implement "partial" for object schemas.

This is the gist of it:

```
function partial(objectSchema) {
  const partial: any = {};
  for (const [key, schema] of Object.entries(objectSchema.fields)) {
    partial[key] =
    "optional" in schema && schema.optional instanceof Function
    ? schema.optional()
    : schema;
  }
  
  objectSchema.fields = partial

  return  objectSchema
}
```

The typescript seems like it might be kind of a mess to hook up if you implement it yourself.